# Creating certificate chain on keytool or Keystore Explorer

Tags: android, certificate, keystore

I have a certificate issued by a CA "GeoTrust". According to their website I must include two more intermediate certificates in order to create a certificate chain. The goal is to establish "TLS" with Firebase Cloud messaging.

I have Keystore Explorer. I opened the keystore whose key was validated by GeoTrust when they issued me the free-trial SSL certificate.

On the keypair icon in Keystore Explorer I right clicked and then selected "import CA reply from file" I selected the file that was issued by Geotrust to me for my keystore. Keystore Explorer says that the public keys matched in both my keystore public key and their issued Free Trial SSL certificate. Now, how in the world do I include the other two intermediate certificates using keystore explorer. I have been following this stackoverflow answer ***[How to create a certificate chain using keytool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634658/how-to-create-a-certificate-chain-using-keytool)***  but i see that in there you have to create different keypairs which ask you to create different common names. I don't think that is the right way in order to include my intermediate certificates. Could someone please point me in the right direction.  This process of establishing "TLS" handshake with keystores is getting very annoying on top of that I must establish SASL plain authentication with Firebase CCS which is probably even more annoying since I have to somehow create a server to do that.

Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Tools>Import Trusted Certificate

Comment: Right-click on the key pair entry and select "Edit Certificate Chain -> Append Certificate". You can check the chain then by double clicking on the key pair entry.

Comment: Well I have two intermediate certificates that I need to add to the chain. Only one of the two is being added the other is not. it tells me "the chosen certificate was not used to sing the end of the chain" @Omikron

Comment: Well, if KSE says so, it's probably correct. On the GeoTrust website there is one intermediate CA for "Free Trial SSL" under a SHA-1 root and one intermediate CA under a SHA-2 root (https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO28816). You need only one of these two.